# sifr-active gets applied the <html>

Tags: sifr

A quick question,
I am having trouble applying sifr to some h1 tags. I have never ran into this problem before but now I just can't figure out what is wrong.
I am applying sifr to some h1 tags but the sifr-active class gets applied to the html tag rather then the tag that sifr is replacing.
Any ideas why this might be happening?
Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Is it not meant to apply sifr-active to the element that the sifr is being applied to. example, I am applying sifr to an h1 tag with the class title.
the select would be h1.title and the tag would end up looking like
<h1 class="title sifr-active">
However my MAIN html is tag is getting the sifr-active so its being
<html class="sifr-active">

that means when I apply the css visibility:hidden to the sifr-active, to hide the initial text, it hides the entire page instead

Answer (score 1):

I have indeed fixed it.

After viewing the demo in the css you use

```
.sIFR-active h1 {}
```

Simple as that